# Decreasing Tesseract OCR Execution time

Tags: c++, computer-vision, ocr, tesseract

i made a Optical Character Recognition program by using Tesseract, however it works slower than its intended to. Im using ocrb traineddata which i found on github and  i believe creating my own trained data with smaller size will increase execution speed. I'm relatively new to OCR so do you have any tips to increase time efficiency? Maybe an alternative for Pix?

Its runtime is 0.1 second in my computer, it would be perfect if its below 0.066. Here is my function:

```
 std::string imageToText() {

    tesseract::TessBaseAPI api;
    api.Init("./tessdata", "ocrb_int");
    Pix* image = pixRead("randommrz.jpg");
    api.SetImage(image);

    return api.GetUTF8Text();
}
```

Also i'm aware of lack of garbage collecting

Comment: @AlanBirtles Typo, edited the question. Thanks for the notice

Comment: The very first thing to check is whether or not you have enabled compiler optimizations when building your code. By default almost all compilers produce unoptimized debug builds for ease of debugging. Such builds are rather slow. You want to make sure you test a optimized release build.

Answer (score 3):

Okay so i was able to reduce running time to 0.036 secs, im writing my steps for future devs :)

1. I used CMAKE and included only neccessary libraries, i dont know how much this effected the running time but i guess it's good practice.
2. I trained my own data with tesseract, took a lot of trial/error but finally managed to create a new one with good time/accuracy tradeoff.
3. I did preprocessing manually with OpenCV, didn't use leptonica ( `pixRead()` etc.)
   First problem i encountered in this step was: `tessApi->SetImage()` function takes `Pix* object` , but there is a overloaded option which you can use like:

   ```
   tesseract::TessBaseAPI* tess = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
   cv::Mat image = cv::imread("filename.png");
   /*
   Preprocessing
   */
   tess->SetImage(image.data, image.cols, image.rows, 3, image.step);

   return tessApi->GetUTF8Text();
   ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If you do not need OpenCV elsewhere - do not use it. leptonica is much lighter and tesseract use it way and created PIX anyway. So reading to image to OpenCV and than to transform it to PIX, could be useless step.

Comment: Hey, i am using OpenCV in MRZ detection step, in my code `cv::Mat image` object is the MRZ zone extracted from whole image. I didn't include that part to make is simple. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 2):

If you are interesting in speed improvement you have to measure each step and whole process. This can give you better picture what is possible to expected:

1. **tesseract initialization** - smaller data (ocrb_int) can help, but disk access is limitation (e.g. accessing tesseract library). Also removing some tesseract features could decrease tesseract size - search on internet)
2. **image loading** - disk access and image size is your limitation. You can play with different image format
3. **OCR process** itself - image preprocessing can help in this stage (but it will cost you something anyway)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. 3. step made me look from another perspective which resulted in success. I'm writing things i changed / added in my answer

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/tesseract-with-cuda/47987/2) tesseract has some OpenCl support so running it in a GPU could improve performance.

If that is not an option you could minimize the data to be processed. Try not to load the full image but only the part containing text. This is called [CRAFT](https://paperswithcode.com/paper/character-region-awareness-for-text-detection), however i could find mainly python implementations.

Comment: Hey Nick, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately running in GPU is not an option for me, i'll Wrap this function into Java using JNI, and i'm currently using cropped images which only contains text part. I will also implement OpenCV part to detect text blocks before, then recognize whatever inside. 

I believe only way to improve time efficiency is using better traineddata. How Google Vision API does this job in miliseconds is driving me crazy.

Comment: this may be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39300753/how-to-make-tesseract-faster#39301578